# Can Google Calendar still automatically detect events in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, google-calendar

I seem to recall a few years ago when Google Calendar first came out, that it regularly detected events in your email, and proposed turning them into Calendar items. It would look for words like "when: tomorrow" etc, and parse them.

These days it doesn't do that. Is there a way to get this functionality back? Did Google ditch it for some reason?

Comment: Reviving this because Google 2022 is becoming a memory hole of useless popular searches compared to what they were in 2010, or earlier. I *think* this is because of the 2009 patent US20110106892A1. I assert that software patents that last more than ~2 years are worse than useless.

Comment: Ah, thanks for linking that.

Answer (score 3):

While it won't automatically turn email data into a calendar event, Google Calendar will still [detect 'event information' and display an 'Add to calendar' option](http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=47802).

To keep the full email text in the event item you can also forward the email to yourself and choose 'Add Event Invitation'. More information about this option is available on the [Google Calendar forums](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Calendar/thread?tid=4f9e5587587f06a5&hl=en).

Comment: Ok, so if someone explicitly attaches "event information", then it will offer to add it to the calendar, but it doesn't automatically parse it from email text.

Am I dreaming? Did it never do that?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I remember it doing this too.

Comment: Yes. It did do that http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2007/10/create-google-calendar-events-from.html